# How to avoid duplicating tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to store information on dates planned and dates taken in a database. The database needs to be very scalable and efficient. Should I remove the `Dates` table and place `DateTaken` and `DatesPlanned` into different databases? My only reluctance is there are multiple tables that rely on `DateId`. Is there a better solution that wouldn't require duplicate tables that need `DateId`?

```
CREATE TABLE Dates
(
    DateId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ProfileId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (DateId, ProfileId)
);

CREATE TABLE DateTaken
(
    DateId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    DateStart DATE NOT NULL,
    DateEnd DATE NOT NULL,
    Summary VARCHAR(1500),
    FOREIGN KEY (DateId) REFERENCES Dates(DateId)
);

CREATE TABLE DatePlanned
(
    DateId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    DateStart DATE NOT NULL,
    DateEnd DATE NOT NULL,
    Summary VARCHAR(1500),
    FOREIGN KEY (DateId) REFERENCES Dates(DateId)
);

CREATE TABLE DateRestaurant
(
    RestaurantId INT NOT NULL,
    DateId INT NOT NULL,
    CheckIn DATE NOT NULL,
    CheckOut DATE NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (DateId, RestaurantId),
    FOREIGN KEY (DateId) REFERENCES Dates(DateId)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you are splitting the table because you want to give them another function meaning. Why? I guess it is all about a restaurant order.

So, just merge the two tables together, add a field (or some fields) for the `planned status` or a second table that keeps a log of the status changes (planned, check-in, check-out) and voila, you are done.

**EDIT**

Instead of adding a status field to the table, I would suggest to add a table `OrderStatus` which contains `DateId`, `Status`, `StartDate`, maybe `EndDate` and `Summary`. I this way you can update the status every time, add as much as you like, can cancel and reopen again, etc.

Comment: I have multiple other tables that require `DateId`. Adding a fields for each is not practical. I really like the idea of adding a status to the restaurant table.

Comment: Excellent idea. However The only change I would make is remove `DateId` from all restaurants. Then maintain a two small table with `RestaurantId` and `DateId`. That way i can have Restaurant in a separate DB.

Comment: Why a separate DB? Table, okay, but database?